# HTML input using exonym suggestions

Tags: html, internationalization, user-experience

I am creating a website in German. No big deal I am nativ speaker.

If I misspell "Mittelsmann" by left the last character I have this suggestion from chrome:

[image]

This is usefull and I like to keep this behavior. But this input-field is an exception because it requires a scientific value and should be in english, so all suggestions for german words are basically wrong (call to Seiri of Kaizen).

Question: How can I force the suggestion to be in english for this input field ONLY?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very good question. I'm German myself and ran into the same problem last year.

There are suggestions to let the HTML `lang` attribute decide which spellcheck is used ([see the chromium developer discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389498) ending with WontFix/Closed). But sadly a lot of the current browsers (especially native browsers of the OS, and all mobile keyboards of cause) use the external spell checking provided by the OS.
So your wanted feature doesn't exist (resp. no standard for that), because a customized/picked language by JavaScript is often not transferable to the spell checker.

I solved my problem by adding and activating both languages German and English to my spell checker in Google Chrome, which resulted in getting both suggestions. That's not satisfying, but it worked for me.

**Edit:**
I also see a lot of German sites solving that problem by using attributes like `autocorrect="off"`, `autocapitalize="off"` and `spellcheck="false"` on an "just English" input field to avoid confusing the user by German spelling suggestions and corrections. May that be an option to you?